# What is the size, in pixels, of AdSize.BANNER?

Tags: android, admob, adview

In my Android app, I have an AdView:

```
AdView adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, MY_BANNER_UNIT_ID);
```

How do I get the size of this in pixels?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As mentioned in the answer by Flynn, an adView is 320 dp by 50 dp.  To convert 50 dp to pixels, do

```
(int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 50, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
```

(and similarly for 320 dp).

Comment: Alse you can convert in this way
DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
  getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);

  final int addHeight = (int) Math.ceil(50 * metrics.density);

Answer (score 13):

You can use following methods from the [`AdSize`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/ads/AdSize.html) class to get its size in pixels:

1. [`getWidthInPixels(Context context)`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/ads/AdSize.html#getWidthInPixels(android.content.Context)),
2. [`getHeightInPixels(Context content)`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/ads/AdSize.html#getHeightInPixels(android.content.Context)).

Comment: This is the correct answer but unfortunately came late I guess.

Answer (score 7):

An adView is 320x50, and if the view does not fit, then it is not displayed.

http://code.google.com/mobile/ads/docs/android/intermediate.html

Comment: No. You get 4 sizes that cannot be changed.

Comment: Isn't that is dp's (not pixels)?

Comment: The developer site does not say, however in my personal experience the measure must be in dp because it always fills perfectly on phones

Comment: Have you checked SMART_BANNER yet. I guess they takes screen width in consideration